# React router get currently active segment as param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have following router configuration

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={ReviewWizard}>
        <IndexRoute component={Administrative}/>

        <Route path="Administrative" component=Administrative}>
            <Route path="/Administrative/:itemId" component={AdministrativeItem}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="Offense" component={Offense}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I'm trying to get currently active route segment (ie `Administrative` or `Offense`).

Is there a way to do something like this? ie route constraints

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/:segment" component={ReviewWizard}>
        <IndexRoute component={Administrative}/>

        <Route path="/:segment=Administrative/:itemId" component={Administrative}>
            <Route path="/Administrative/:itemId" component={AdministrativeItem}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:segment=Offense" component={Offense}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

If not, what is best practice to get the current active route segment? I don't like `this.context.router.routes[1].path`

Comment: seems it will make your path as `/Administrative/Administrative/:itemId`, is that right?

Comment: @fumi_hwh yes. I do want to slice one /Administrative :)

Answer (score 3):

First off I would recommend the following router config, as it seems that it's what you're aiming for:

```
<Router history={history}>

  <Route path="/" component={ReviewWizard}>

    <!-- whenever we hit '/' we redirect to '/Administrative' -->
    <IndexRedirect path="/Administrative"/>

    <!-- Renders ReviewWizard <- Administrative -->
    <Route path="/Administrative" component={Administrative}>

      <!-- Renders ReviewWizard <- Administrative <- AdministrativeItem -->
      <Route path="/Administrative/:itemId" component={AdministrativeItem}/>

    </Route>

    <!-- Renders ReviewWizard <- Offense -->
    <Route path="/Offense" component={Offense}/>

  </Route>

</Router>
```

As for detecting the currently active route (or if a route fragment is active), I would recommend using [the `router.isActive` -method](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#isactivepathorloc-indexonly). Simply do something like this:

```
if (router.isActive('/Administrative')) {
  doSomething()
} else if (router.isActive('/Offense')) {
  doSomethingElse()
}
```

For something more declarative, I recommend just using [the location object](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#location) that `react-router` injects into each component it manages:

```
const { location: { pathname } } = this.props
const [ activeSegment ] = pathname.slice(1).split('/')
```

Hope these help!

Comment: Thank you! Actually I use the same approach already. Just finding a declarative way